# how to put elements around circle with equal distance?

Tags: unity, mathematics, unityscript

I know circle formula and know how to draw it. but I want put 4 points on it with equal distance from each other. how can I do that?

I work with unity.

Comment: This solves it: https://answers.unity.com/questions/714835/best-way-to-spawn-prefabs-in-a-circle.html

Comment: @LinkWindcrafter thanks. I had to guess. I have to use traigonometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make a [regular polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon). It also sounds like you're talking about 2D space, but just for fun, here's a way to do that for any number of points and any arbitrary circle in 3D space:

```
public Vector3[] circlePoints (int n, float radius, Vector3 center, Vector3 normal) {
    var points = new Vector3[n];

    Vector3 offset = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(Vector3.right, normal).normalized * radius;
    float angle = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Vector3 rotatedOffset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, normal) * offset;
        points[i] = center + rotatedOffset;

        angle += 360f / n;
    }

    return points;
}
```

Set `normal` so that it's perpendicular to the circle you want to draw on. So if your game is 2D, use `Vector3.forward`, since that's perpendicular to the XY plane.

However, for a 2D game or one where every circle is on the same (axis-aligned) plane, I would just go with a trigonometric solution.